# Migrating to role-based support subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an Invoice Billing Account with GCP and I am trying to understand the migration from old support to the new Role-Based Support. Do I need to speak to a sales agent? Or can I do this on my own? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to Google Billing Support, not SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/migration#q_what_steps_are_necessary_to_migrate) documentation, you can migrate by yourself.

> To enable Role-Based Support:
>
> 1.Log into the GCP Console as an Organization Administrator.
>
> 2.Select the organization for which you want to enable Role-Based Support.
>
> 3.Go to the [Support page](https://console.cloud.google.com/support?_ga=2.99305374.-1623833512.1561982721) and open Cases.
>
> 4.Click Enable, and then follow the on-screen prompts to complete the required steps.
>
> 5.Submit your request.

Also check the quick migration training [video](https://youtu.be/NdDabRpG-BI).